# How to differentiate between superscript indices and powers in the output?

Tags: output-formatting, custom-notation, feyncalc

I have ambiguous notation in my output.

I have output that has two types of superscripts, indices and powers. The indices range from {none,0,1,2,3} and typical powers are 2 or 4.

When there is an superscript index with a power it is clear to see and or if the power is 4 or higher. However, ambiguity lies in deciphering between powers of 2 or 3 and superscript indices of 2 and 3.

I was wondering if there is a way to force the out put of powers to be in parentheses or a different color?

I am using the package FeynCalc to work through some gnarly Dirac matrix traces.

Here is a picture of the output that I am struggling with.
[image: Sample output with ambigous indices]

**Update**

I thought that switching the output form to standard fixed the issue... however it did not. Here is the same output as above but in standard form.

[image: Standard form]

I tried looking for questions that answer this... So if this has been asked before, I apologize.

Comment: I assume this will be unacceptable: Superscript[x, Style[2, Red]]^3 which will make your superscript red and leave the rest of your text black. I don't know how or even if that will play well with the FeynCalc package. And I don't know if it might be possible to use substitutions after-the-fact to wrap your superscripts in Style[ ,Red]. You might try such a pattern substitution on your exponents instead of your superscripts after the fact and see if you can get something that is acceptable.

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the standard form output? On your screenshot I see that all components in powers are of the form (p^i)^n, so there is no ambiguity what is the component and what is the exponent.

Comment: @ vsht Through dimensional analysis I was able to infer which was what and who was who. The parentheses do not always denote powers.  For instance the third term is the magnitude of the four momentum k not the second spatial component of the four momentum. Soooo maybe I guess the way to look at this....which is maybe what you were getting at is... there is either: (p^i)^n or p^n.

Answer (score 3):

FeynCalc actually makes very little usage of `ExplicitLorentzIndex`. Such
indices are not summed over but there are also no simplifications attached
to them.

Anyhow, I've just added an option called `TypesettingExplicitLorentzIndex` to the
development version. This way you can define the formatting of `ExplicitLorentzIndex`
according to your preferences.

So if you reinstall FeynCalc via

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/master/install.m"]
InstallFeynCalc[InstallFeynCalcDevelopmentVersion -> True]
```

you can do things like

```
exp = 4 M^2 u FV[k, 0]^2 - 4 M^2 u FV[k, 3]^2 - 4 M SP[k, k] - 
  2 M u FV[k, 0] FV[k, 3]^2 + 4 M u FV[k, 0] FV[k, 2] - u^2 FV[k, 2]^2

TypesettingExplicitLorentzIndex = Function[x, Style[x, Red]]

exp

TypesettingExplicitLorentzIndex = Function[x, Style[x, Bold]]

exp
```

[image]

which should be what you want.